# QueryDsl models partially getting generated but in build it throws error SpringBoot 2.7.14 and queryDsl 5

Tags: spring-boot, build.gradle, querydsl, gradle-plugin

i have multimodule spring-boot gradle project which i want to upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.7 (springboot version). And in process QueryDSL also needs to be upgraded from 4.1.3 to 5.0

Without upgrade everything is working as expected and files are getting generated during build.

But after upgrade to above versions, I am facing two issues :

1. queryDsl models getting generated but not recognized during gradle build, so getting build failure.
2. querydsl models not generated for submodule which has internally dep of queryDsl 4.1.3 (not changed)

Project Structure

rootProject

- build.gradle
- sub Module

  - build.gradle

I tried approach mentioned in [QueryDSL issue with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280005/querydsl-issue-with-gradle) but it didnt work